# Figures of the patent

Tags: patent-figures

In reference to the patent: [EP2877714A1](https://www.google.com/patents/EP2877714A1)

Where can I find the figures the patent referes to?

Answer (score 1):

1. On the page you linked, at the top right, you should see a box with some meta-information about the article. It includes a section called "External Links" which includes a link called "Espacenet".  Click that link.
2. On the left side of the resulting Espacenet page you should see a link called "Mosaics".  Click that.
3. You should now be able to see the figures. Here's a direct link:

https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/mosaics?CC=EP&NR=2877714A1&KC=A1&FT=D&ND=&date=20150603&DB=&locale=